# What would be the difference in pronunciation of "kid show" and "kid's show"?

Tags: pronunciation

Going from that /z/ sound to /ʃ/ sound feels clumsy and unnatural. Does it get assimilated or something?

Comment: It is an individual thing because many people will use kid as an adjective, not a possessive.

Comment: From /s/ to /ʃ/ or from **/z/** to /ʃ/? Because the **'s** is pronounced /z/ in *kid's* and it isn't unnatural at all.

Comment: @Void you're correct I'll edit

Comment: I pronounce the hard "s" on "kid's" as a /z/ sound, and then sort of mush that into the soft "s" on "show." The result is that the "sh" of "show" becomes almost a "zh" as in the Chinese name **Zhou Enlai**: *KID-zhow." But I can enunciate the sibilant "s" and articulate it from the "sh" if I want to.

Comment: Yes - for the most part, that intervening "voiced /s/" between two unvoiced consonants gets "assimilated". With most speakers in most contexts you might feasibly notice a *very* brief "hiatus / glottal stop" at that point, but the "articulation" is as much in the mind as it is in the mouth, in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I say 'kid_ show'. The underscore line is my way of showing that the /d/ is held for longer than normal and then it goes straight into the /ʃ/.

In very careful speech, I can say 'kids show' /kɪdz ʃəʊ/ but it has a forced quality to it and it interrupts the flow of speech.